# Codename one application is not able to connect with server using https request

Tags: codenameone

We have created codename one application which using https request.

I have not made any changes in code.

Earlier the request could be sent using https but now their is a problem and i am unable to connect to the server using https request but i am able to connect same https url using postman.

```
The connection code snippet is following please refer it    
new APIHandler().PropertiesLoad();
        ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest() {
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
                if (code != 200) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        };
        req.setUrl(properties.getProperty("https_url"));
        req.setPost(true);
        req.setTimeout(Constant.TIMEOUT);
        req.addArgument("FirstName", fName;
        req.addArgument("SecondName", sName);
        req.addArgument("BirthDate", bDate);
        req.addArgument("Password", pWord);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addErrorListener((e) -> e.consume());
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);
        byte[] data = req.getResponseData();
        if (data == null) {

        }
        result = new String(data);

    } catch (Exception e) {             
        //get nullpointer exception because result get null
        result = "";
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: What's the error from the HTTPS server? What certificate authority did you use for that server? Do you see this in the simulator, device both? Which ones on which OS and which JDK version if it's the simulator? Minor JDK version numbers are important here...

Comment: It is already working but now it is not able to connect with server. Their is no error only get exception as null pointer exception. Yes we saw this on both simulator. The jdk version we use JDK  1.8.0_151.

Comment: Please see above code snippet which use to connection with server

Comment: @ShaiAlmog hello, Is it any update from you in codename one that is should do we necessary to update in project?

Comment: If the error you got is due to HTTPS but works with HTTP it's a configuration issue unrelated to Codename One. I suggest listing the exception you got and the relevant line that triggered it and looking in the network monitor to see if there are further hints that can point you to the cause of this